# Which Cassandra node to use?

Tags: cassandra, load-balancing, cassandra-2.0

I'm new to Cassandra.

I've deployed a Cassandra 2.0 cluster and everything works as expected.

There's one thing I don't understand, though.

From within a web app that uses the database, to which node should I connect? I know they're all the same, but how do I know that node isn't down?

I read that you're not supposed to use a load balancer, so I'm a little confused.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which driver you are using to connect, you can typically provide more than one node to connect to.  Usually in the form of "node1, node2" ("192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2")

Comment: Got it. Is that the standard way..? That seems like a pain to have to go change the app every time you add nodes...

Comment: Again, depending on your driver it will use auto-discovery to find new nodes.  Here is documentation of the Java driver from DataStax: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/common/drivers/reference/nodeDiscovery_r.html

Comment: Thanks, sonofaforester. I'm mainly wondering how Usergrid does that, i.g. if there is a setting to specify multiple IP addresses, but you definitely put me on the right track.